# How to find out the delivery adress using paypal "add to cart" button?

Tags: paypal

I have a website and intend to use paypals "add to cart" button to buy items.

After reading on paypals developer page my understanding is that once the buyer push the button, the flow is controlled by paypal. This is nice, but i want to deliver world wide and have different shipping cost depending on the delivery adress. Apperantly, if you are a US user this can be done in the settings on the paypal acount. But users outside US dont seem to have this option.

The shipping cost is evaluated depending on attributes of the product, not where to deliver. I contacted paypal support and they refer to manipulating the html code in the button, but i have no idea what the delivery adress is, isnt that paypals duty to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal does have some limited features for helping with shipping, but it sounds like you've already out-grown what it would offer.

What I would recommend for you is using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) instead of standard PayPal buttons.  This allows you to more tightly integrate PayPal payments into your website / application, and you can collect the address from the buyer and calculate shipping using your own resources.  This could be an actual shipping API to pull real-time rates from, it could be some simple formula you setup in your own code, or whatever you want to do to calculate the shipping based on the address entered by the buyer during checkout.

If you are working with PHP this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the API calls for Express Checkout very quick and easy for you.

Comment: Thanks, i will check out express checkout api.